# NTFS partition got merged and contents not showing

Tags: partitioning

I had a 750GB NTFS partition, 100GB NTFS partition and 100GB ext4 partition.
Recently I formatted my 100GB NTFS partition to ext4 partition with live ubuntu cd.
After that, the partitions were changed to 850GB ext4 and 100 GB ext4.
All my data of 750GB NTFS is also not showing now. Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Stop using the computer immediately!

It sounds like you did more than just create an ext4 filesystem on the 100 GB partition. You don't say *how* you did this, so I can't say what your (presumed) mistake was, but chances are you accidentally operated on the wrong partition or even accidentally did much more extensive partitioning operations.

I can't really be more specific without more specific information, such as a screen shot of GParted or the output of `sudo parted -l`. (You can do this from a boot of a live USB disk to minimize the risk of doing further damage.)

If I'm right, though, your best hope for full recovery is to restore files from a backup. If you don't have a backup, your best hope for partial recovery is to use a tool like [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) to extract files from the disk onto a separate recovery medium. Some Windows-specific tools are said to do a better job recovering filenames than PhotoRec, but I don't have pointers to specific tools. If I'm right, the odds of your getting your system back to the state it was in before the accident are pretty slim, unless of course you have a recent backup, in which case you can use it.

Comment: Output:

Model: ATA WDC WD10EZEX-00U (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  100GB   100GB   primary  ext4
 2      100GB   105GB   4859MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
 4      105GB   1000GB  895GB   primary  ext4


Model: Generic Flash Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 4209MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  4209MB  4208MB  primary  fat32        boot, lba

Comment: I got the above output after firing sudo parted -l command. Sorry for the jumbled output.

Comment: In the future, please edit your question to add program output, and format it appropriately (add four spaces to the start of each line to preserve formatting). In any event, your output supports my hypothesis: You've accidentally trashed your Windows installation. See the duplicate question link in the comments to your question for more help.